# Find Files with 0x00 content

Tags: regex, windows, grep

I'm looking for a simple and fast way to search files that only contain 0x00. It's a 8TB harddisk and some copying went wrong. The filenames and sizes are OK, but they only contain 0x00. I've tried wingrep with `\x00{100}` that works, but searches the whole file and counts how often pattern will match and that will take too much time. So I've written a short C++ program, that will do this job by only reading the first 100 bytes, but I'm interested how I can use regex to tell that it should only check the first match, and then continue to the next file?

Thank you - it works with  `\A.*?\x00{100}. But this will find all matches in the file - even at the end. I've looked but didn't found a a flag which will limit the search area (for example from index 0 to index 101). OK - I've done this in my program, but is it possible just to use regex for this?

Comment: Try `\A.*?\x00{100}`

Comment: Maybe note that `\A` and `*?` are Perl extensions which are not portably supported by most `grep` implementations. If you have GNU `grep`, try `grep -P` to enable these features.

Comment: @tripleee OP mentions `wingrep` (actually, it is `grepWin`), it is based on .NET regex library.

Comment: Try enabling "Only one instance" checkbox option.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `grep`, I suppose you have a Linux subsystem or a Cygwin on your Windows computer, for simulating Linux commands.

One of those commands is `head`, which allows only to see the first `n` bytes (`head -c`) or lines (`head -n`). You can use this as an input for your `grep`.

Comment: They say they are using "wingrep" but I can't find out what the features of this tool are.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -m 1` finds the first match and quits. `grep -l` similarly quits after finding a match and printing the file name.  But if your task is really to find files which don't contain anything else, I guess you want `grep -L '[^\x00]'`
(assuming you have a GNU-like `grep` which supports the `-L` option and the `\x00` hex escape).

If you have Python, here's a simple program to check all your files.

```py
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path('c:/').rglob('*'):
    if not file.is_file():
        continue
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb') as fh:
            found = False
            nonempty = False
            while not found:
                buf = fh.read(1024)
                for byte in buf:
                    nonempty = True
                    if byte != b'\x00':
                        found = True
                if len(buf) < 1024:
                    if not found and not nonempty:
                        print(file)
                    break
    except PermissionError as err:
        print(file, err)
```

The `nonempty` check is to exempt empty files, which of course do not contain any bytes at all (the main logic reads null bytes and gives up when it finds a byte which is not null).